# Postgres: Create index on that text is null or not

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose we have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE public."Comments"
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"Comments_id_seq"'::regclass),
    comment text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT "Comments_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

We need to fast select rows where `comment IS NULL` or where `comment IS NOT NULL`, but we do not need full text search.

Is it possible somehow create an index for that, but not creating full-text index?

Comment: try partial index?..

Comment: `create index on "Comments" (id) where comment is not null`?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid the need for quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble in the long run than they are worth

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know it, it's legacy code moved from MySQL. Anyway, it is unrelated to the question.

Comment: @BennjoeMordeno: that is not true for Postgres. You can easily index values that are much larger then 900 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An index will only help you if the `WHERE` condition is selective, that is, it filters out a significant percentage of the rows. Indeed, PostgreSQL will prefer the more efficient sequential scan if the condition is not selective.

So you cannot have an index that helps with both cases, but you can have an index that may help with the less frequent of these cases.

If comments are usually NULL, you could use:

```
CREATE INDEX ON "Comments" (id) WHERE comment IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition to Laurenz's answer, if you have not so many cases where comment is null, you could just use a btree index since they can be used to look this up:

```
create index comments_comment_idx ON "Comments" (comment);
```

This gives you an ability to search on equality of comments as long as they are short enough not to be toasted.  You can also search for ranges and prefixes.   However if they go on for a few kb, you may start to run into problems, so recommend using this approach only if comments are expected to be reasonably short.

As a further note there are other ways of optimising such a query as well.  As a further note, if you are doing a lot of ordering by id you may want to do a multi-column index that would allow an index-only scan:

```
create index comments_comment_id_idx ON "Comments" (id, comment);
```

That would be useful if you want the last five ids where comment is not null for example.